# Combining polygon file with multiple overlapping polygons to represent only 1 attribute in given area e.g. highest/lowest/average in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve, arcgis-10.5, union

I have a large shapefile that I'm working with in ArcGIS 10.5 with an ArcInfo license.

At any given location in the file there are multiple polygons.

In the example I am working on there is a particular value; overlapping animal ranges.

There is a value associated with each of these ranges (polygons), and I'd like simply represent the largest value of several overlapping polygons (I might also want to show the high, low or some other statistics).   So any given area will be represented by a single polygon, and a single area.

I was able to dissolve and 'split' the overlapping .shp file into it's constituent parts and I tried 'unioning' them back together with the largest value as the highest priority.

I also tried 'merge' with no luck.  This seems like it should be simple,  but I keep running into a brick wall.

Comment: In QGIS you could style the layer to give colour attributes to the ranges that you want to display and then you could just turn styles on and off as needed. It sounds like you are overcomplicating it by trying to merge and union polygons.

Comment: That's a good point,  but for the purposes of converting these overlapping polygons to a simple .kml and webmap,  I can't have any overlapping polygons.

Answer (score 4):

In Arcmap you would achieve this in 6 steps which can be easily strung together as a model.

You basically Union the layer itself, extract out the centroid XY's, create an ID based upon the centroid XY (a string field concatenating the X and the Y) and it is that that allows you to generate aggregated statistics for the overlapping regions.

[image: Initial sample data]

*Sample data - overlapping polygons labelled with value*

[image: The model]

*The model*

[image: Done]

*The data with summary table joined backed to Union dataset using the common XY string field and symbolised by MAX value*

Comment: Is there a way to do this that results in with zero overlapping polygons,  and only the MAX value of any given area represented by a single polygon.   The most important thing is to remove overlapping polygons.   A given area that was previously represented by multiple polygons will now have only show the polygon of highest value.

Comment: ehh... Yes, _Exactly_ what I just said in the answer above...

Comment: Ok, I might not be understanding what you did.  It looks like e.g. the #11 polygon underlies the #30 polygon.  So it's just symbolizing the Max value,  which is nice,  but there are still polygons underlying.

Comment: Two steps are missing in above solution: delete identical from union and joining summary table back to what remains. But it is a legit solution.

Comment: @FelixIP is correct, not sure why I did not include the delete identical tool in the model, probably because it's an _Advance_ level tool but there others ways to identify duplicates and remove them.

Comment: Watching discussions on this forum I am often surprised how overly cautious, academic style some users are. It would take a couple of minutes to test your solution and make a conclusion. Takes less time than writing comment etc. Perhaps it just me slow non English speaker typist:)